# can't connect to internet in ONLY in my android app. Each method to connect internet returns null

Tags: android, url, null, httpurlconnection

I am using `HttpURLConnection`'s connect method but it returns `null`.
no other message no printstack just null.

```
URL url = new URL("http://whatever");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

In above also it returns the null

Don't know why this comes. But I cant connect to net.

i also tried with HttpURLConnection and urlconnection both are different example.

Comment: Have you added the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Add below permissions in manifest file-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: is there any error or warning in logcat?post your logcat info

Comment: no in the try catch block i used getmessage() it just print the null

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using `HttpURLConnection` but in the code you poste `URLConnection`. This is how you make a proper `HttpURLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  readStream(in);
 finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect();
 }
}
```

You also have to do this connection outside the main thread (Using `AsyncTask` or other method) or otherwise the app will crash.

Also add the right permissions for it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope it helps! Good Luck!

Comment: sorry,but i tested with both urlconnection and httpurlconnection. both are different example.