# Network Requests return null - Android

Tags: java, android, networking, null, httpurlconnection

i am working on a network communication project in android, but my app dose not work ! after some debugging, i find out that every network request has a null response from system.

i tried so many ways such as :
1) hard restart my phone
2) adding all network permissions to the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

3) using local network ( my phone as a server )
4) letting all applications to connect to the network : setting > networked apps > ...

but ! nothing happened...

this is my similar problem link, but there is no answer in this topic:
[can't connect to internet in ONLY in my android app. Each method to connect internet returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108206/cant-connect-to-internet-in-only-in-my-android-app-each-method-to-connect-inte)

network is working on my phone because some apps like telegram and chrome are working well !

and there is a funny thing here, when i copy and past this code to the simple java project not android project, it works well !

because i wanted to find out where is the problem, i just copy 3 simple lines of codes  to the simple android project, but still nothing happened!

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dltests"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

source file

```
package com.example.dltests;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        try 
        {
            URL mUrl = new URL("http://192.168.1.53:8080/some.zip");
            HttpURLConnection mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            mTextView.setText(mHttpURLConnection.getContentLength());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            mTextView.setText("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

and the result is : 
ERROR: null

Comment: Log the exception to see NetworkOnMainThreadException, and then think what the exception name means.

Comment: Are you sure your phone can acess that URL?  What happens if you use the phone's web browser to go to http://192.168.1.53:8080/HiSuiteSetup_2.3.55.1.zip?

Comment: @laalto : yes exactly ! that's the error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @elevine : opening download application

Comment: @laalto is on the right track then.  You need to do the download on a different thread.

Comment: sorry for this simple question :( thanks for your attention

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android bars you from networking in the UI thread. What you need to do it spawn a separate thread to do the networking for you. Then you need either a receiver or handler to post/update the UI with the data.

1 - Create a new class:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class GetData extends Thread
{

    // Holds url that data is stored on
    private URL url

    // Sets the url value
    public GetData(URL newUrl)
    {
         url = newUrl;
    }

    // Runs when the thread is launched
    public void run()
    {
        // Opens connection
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Sends back to UI using a Message
        Message msg = MainActivity.MainActivityInterface.obtainMessage(MainActivity.getAndUpdate);
        msg.obj = con.getContentLength(); // Adds the data
        HomeScreen.homeScreenInterface.sendMessage(msg); 
    }
}
```

2 - Create handler in activity so UI can be updated as well as launch worker thread

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Holds activity instance
    public static MainActivity currentInstance;

    // Variable that allows us to separate messages for handler
    public static final getAndUpdate = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentInstance = this;
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        try 
        {
            URL mUrl = new URL("http://192.168.1.53:8080/some.zip");

            // Spawns worker thread
            GetData gd = new GetData(mUrl);
            gd.start();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            mTextView.setText("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Deals with service responses
    public static Handler MainActivityInterface = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch(msg.what)
            {
                case getAndUpdate:
                    currentInstance.mTextView.setText((String) msg.obj); // Gets message object and updates UI
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Note that I have not tested it as I am very far away from my coding computer!